# Display a random customposttype2 excerpt in single-custompostype1.php that shares same taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-posts

OK - Looked everywhere for this one.

**Details:**

Custom Post Type #1 = 'product' > registered taxonomy 'productranges'

Custom Post Type #2 = 'testimonial' > registered taxonomy 'testimonials'

Both CPTs share categories 'Complete Food' , 'Treats', etc.. for example

**Question:**

How can I display a random post excerpt of the same shared-category from a 'Testimonial' post into 'Product' post? In a sense linking the Testimoinals to the Products.

I've used the following but it only shows a random post from all the categories, I need it to output from the current-shared category being viewed:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('post_type=testimonial&issue=$issueid&post_status=publish&numberposts=1&orderby=rand');

foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_excerpt('<div class="readmore">'); ?><a href="/testimonials">read more...</a> 

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php

//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();?>
```

Cheers if you can help!

Comment: Have you tried putting your get_posts in an array?

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure how to call the current-page's taxonomy dynamically in order for the one template to serve all products.

Comment: Is the taxonomy a category?

Comment: Yes - they are categories. The top Taxonomies registered are 'productranges' and 'testimonials'.

Comment: Edited initial post to be more clear...

Comment: Does Milo's answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) of the product post and then set `category` in `get_posts()` to that category's `$category->term_id`.

Comment: Have sorted it (well - kind chap over at Wordpress.org nailed it):[link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-random-cpt1-excerpt-in-single-that-shares-category-with-cpt2?replies=10#post-2943544)